# Image URL JSON parse to UIImageView in app error

Tags: ios, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse an image url through JSON in my iPhone application. 
My json model is built like this:

```
{
   "picture":"link_to_image.jpg",
   "about":"about text here",
   "name":"Name"
}
```

I use this code to parse the itemw in my app:

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData
{
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                         options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    self.titleLabel.text = [json objectForKey:@"name"];
    self.aboutText.text = [json objectForKey:@"about"];
    self.profileImage.image = [json objectForKey:@"picture"];
}
```

And in ViewDidLoad I wrote this:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue
    (DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
       dispatch_async(queue,  ^{
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                        [NSURL URLWithString:@"link_to_my_json_file.php"]];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)
                               withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
```

I've connected the outlets to the items in my .xib-file and the title and about text are successfully parsed to the label and textview. But the image won't parse. The app keeps crashing when I try this for the image.

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could explain what you're doing first.

Comment: (You realize that you're putting an NSString pointer into self.profileImage.image, right?  It's not an image, just its name.)

Comment: (And you also realize that, since you're dispatching that code async, the results from it will not be immediately available, right?)

Comment: And what messages do you get when the app crashes?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm just getting started with Objective-C now... NSLog says: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString _isResizable]:..." @HotLicks

Comment: isResizable is a method on UIImage.  An NSString is not a UIImage.

Comment: (Re-read my second comment.)

Comment: Ok, so how should the code be like? @HotLicks

Comment: Well, since you haven't revealed any of your structures or how you use the resulting data, I guess it's just fine the way you have it.

Answer (score 1):

As @Hot Licks have mentioned in comments you are putting a NSString pointer into UIImage property. Following method should work.

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData
{
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                         options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    self.titleLabel.text = [json objectForKey:@"name"];
    self.aboutText.text = [json objectForKey:@"about"];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString: [json objectForKey:@"picture"]];
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue
    (DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
       dispatch_async(queue,  ^{
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: URL];
        self.profileImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
    });
}
```

Comment: But it needs to be noted that none of those values will be set on exit from the sequence in viewDidLoad, but at some later time.

Comment: I get "Parse Issue Expected identifier" on the line:NSURL *URL = [[NSURL URLWithString: [json objectForKey:@"picture"]];

Comment: @DavidGabor - Count your brackets.

Comment: I have removed one bracket.